# React: useEffect unmount prints out old variable value

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm experiencing problems with the useEffect() method!

I have a **ParentComponent** with a function `doSomething()` that prints out a variable called **names**.

Inside of this component I have a `<Text>` component (which displays the names) and below it I have a **ChildComponent**.

---

In the **ChildComponent** I have a `TextInput` which updates the parent variable **name** on change.

I want to trigger the `doSomething()` function from the **ChildComponent**, whenever the component **unmounts.**

```
// Parent Component
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [names, setNames] = useState('BOB');
  const childRef = useRef(null);

  const doSomething = () => {
    console.log('Did something with the names:' + names)
  };

  return (

  <Text>The names: {names}</Text>
  <ChildComponent
       doSomething={doSomething}
       names={names}
       setNames={setNames}
       ref={childRef}
  </ChildComponent>

  );
};

// Child Component
const ChildComponent = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const {doSomething, names, setNames } = props

  // Load names to input on mount
  React.useEffect(() => {
    textInput.focus();
    textInput.value = names;
  }, []);

  // Do something on willUnmount
  React.useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      doSomething();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
       <TextInput
          value={names}
          onChangeText={text => setNames(text)}
          ref={input => {
            this.textInput = input;
          }}
       />
    </View>
  );
});
```

**The problem is:**

If I edit the names to **"Bob, Andrew"**, the parent `<Text>` component updates its value, however on unmount the `doSomething()` function logs out the old value **"Bob"**

Why is that so?

---

**EDIT:**

I've tried to pass the names in the function from the **ChildComponent**

In the **ChildComponent**:

```
  const [childNames, setChildNames] = useState(names);
  
  // Do something on willUnmount
  React.useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      doSomething(childNames);
    };
  }, [childNames]);
```

But this causes to trigger the `doSomething()` every time the text changes (every keyboard press) - but I want it to be triggered only when the component disappears/unmounts

Comment: When do you expect the child component to unmount? There doesn't seem anything in your code that will cause it to unmount

Comment: @Gee I've reduced the code for better readability. The ChildComponent is actually a SwipeablePanel (rn-swipeable-panel) that unmounts when flicked down.

Comment: I see. It looks to me like it should be working, perhaps there's an issue in the related code that's causing the problem? If you're using your components in an array do you have a key set?

Comment: @Gee Thank you for the reply! In the end Oktay's answer solved my issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an closure problem. When the callback function in useEffect is initialized, the first value of the doSomething is kept in the memory.

This is what happens:

**first render:**

- doSomething knows about the value of names (Bob)
- useEffect stores in the memory the reference of that doSomething, that knows Bob.

**Second render:**

- doSomething is reinitialized again. Now it knows the value of names as 'Bob, Andrew'
- useEffect - since the dependencies does not change, it does not store the new reference of doSomething. It still keeps the old one that knows 'Bob'. This is why it logs you always the initial value.

You can avoid it like this:

```
const ref = useRef()
ref.current = childNames
const doSomething = () => {
   // here use ref.current instead of childNames
   // it has the updated value.
}
useEffect(() => doSomething, [])
```

ref has value {current: ...}. doSomething stores in the memory the reference of the ref. It knows it's reference. The thing useRef returns you never changes its reference. You can only change the property called 'current'